# How to add manufacturer attribute on Checkout Page in Magento 2

Tags: attributes, checkout, magento2, magento-manufacturer

I need add manufacturer attribute next to product name on Checkout Page. I will be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You MageVision Team :-)

https://www.magevision.com/blog/post/get-a-product-attribute-in-checkout-summary-magento-2/